# Will shorter route be less asymmetric than longer route?

Tags: asymmetric-routing

As you may know that due to the dynamic in Internet Infrastructure, the request packet and return packet are not guaranteed to be sent and came back on the same route, which is called asymmetric property of the Internet.

So my question is that: Is it correct to conclude that shorter route will be less asymmetric than longer route? For instance, if 2 ends of a route are located in same Autonomous System, then it is quite sure that request and return packets will traverse over the same route (aka, symmetric route)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asymmetry may occur on two levels:

1. source -> dest takes a different AS-path than dest -> source, so there's a difference in networks traversed
2. within each AS on the path (both source -> dest and dest -> source) different routes can be chosen

For each given source and destination, asymmetry can occur on both levels. As a result, it's very hard to answer your question. It may be true (since there could be less networks and hops involved), but it's hard to give an answer which applies to the general case. Also, anything which may seem to be nearby looking from one end may be further away looking from the other end.